# smooth translation of Search bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

```js
$('#toggle').on('click blur', function() {
    $('.morphsearchinput').toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
.morphsearchinput {
    -webkit-transition: width .8s , height .8s ease, -webkit-transform 2s;
    -moz-transition: width .8s, height .8s ease, -moz-transform 2s;
    -ms-transition: width .8s, height .8s ease;
    -o-transition: width .8s, height .8s ease;
    transition: width .8s, height .8s ease, transform 2s;  
    transform: translate(200px,100px); 
    
    min-width: 50px; 
    min-height: 40px; 
    width: 0%; 
    height: 0%;
    -webkit-animation-name: example;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; 
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {translate(0px,0px);}
    to {translate(200px,100px);}
}


@keyframes example {
    from {translate(0px,0px);}
    to {translate(200px,100px);}
}

.expanded { 
    width: 80% !important; /* !important because min-width is stronger than width */
}


body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="morphsearch-form">
    <input class="morphsearchinput" type="search" placeholder="Search..." id="toggle" />
</form>
```

I want to change the position of search bar when expanded . I want to translate it a little but somehow my code for search bar is not working.
I have also added animation for smooth translation of x and y but it also seems to be not working.

Comment: already did .please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cleaned your CSS code, to let only the needed one.

I removed the `transition` and `keyframe` because it doesn't work.

I added a `position: absolute` with the requested coordinates.

Then, I added a `transform` in the `expanded` class to handle a move to the left for 100px.

I hope it's the wanted result.

```js
$('#toggle').on('click blur', function() {
    $('.morphsearchinput').toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
.morphsearchinput {
  -webkit-transition: width .8s , height .8s ease, -webkit-transform 2s;
  -moz-transition: width .8s, height .8s ease, -moz-transform 2s;
  -ms-transition: width .8s, height .8s ease;
  -o-transition: width .8s, height .8s ease;
  transition: width .8s, height .8s ease, transform 2s;  

  min-width: 50px; 
  min-height: 40px; 
  width: 0%; 
  height: 0%;
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 100px;
}

.expanded { 
    width: 80% !important; /* !important because min-width is stronger than width */
    transform: translate(-100px,0px); 
}


body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="morphsearch-form">
    <input class="morphsearchinput" type="search" placeholder="Search..." id="toggle" />
</form>
```

Comment: this worked fine but can you explain why keyframe won't work here

Comment: The `keyframe` was placed on `.morphsearchinput` which is the "default" state of the search input so it can't work as expected: the animation must start when `click` or `blur`. So "something has to be done" on the `expanded` state.